# Build a matrix with an initial dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I'm new to R.
I'm facing an issue here, I have a dataframe with binary variables which look like this:
[image: initial dataframe]

And I want a dataframe which counts for each row the occurrence (here the output that I want):

[image: The output that I want]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Much preferred to providing images of data would be to [edit] your question to include the same information, but as plain text (preferably within code blocks). You can get this information via the R command `dput(your_data)` (where you replace `your_data` with the actual name of your dataframe); then you can simply copy and paste the output of that command here. This is an easy way for others to see and use your data to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you should supply your data as described in my comment above.
However, as this issue was easy to solve and the data easy to generate,
I provide a solution here:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Algeria = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                  France  = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                  Spain   = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                  Italy   = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))
crossprod(as.matrix(dat))
```

```
        Algeria France Spain Italy
Algeria       4      3     1     3
France        3      5     3     4
Spain         1      3     4     3
Italy         3      4     3     5
```

(R's `crossprod(x)` is the same as `t(x) %*% x`)

I am certain I've seen this trick on Stack Overflow somewhere actually, but I can't find it currently to mark as a duplicate; this may be closed as a duplicate at some point if I or someone else who's better at searching than me can find the duplicate to mark.

---

<sub>You'll notice a couple entries on the `Italy` column disagree with your post, but manual inspection reveals this solution is correct rather than your posted image</sub>